# How can I force the Pi to wake a monitor

Tags: pi-3, display, pi-3b+

This question is not specifically a Pi question, but about how to **FORCE** the Pi `hdmi` to wake my monitor from sleep, which seems to be a seems to be specific to the Pi hardware, although it may be a foible of the monitor.

I have a monitor (Samsung SyncMaster 740B) connected to my Pi.
(The monitor is connected via a DVI-hdmi converter and a 3 port hdmi switch, but even direct connection often fails.)
Normally this works well, however I seem to have problems waking it up.

I normally turn the monitor off when not in use for a period, but on power up the display remains blanked.
The LED in the power button blinks, normally solid when running.
If I leave it in this state (turned on, blank display) it eventually springs to life, but this takes quite some time.
Once it has woken up everything works as normal.

I have tried many ploys to wake it up.
Pressing Shift key usually wakes other computers, but has no effect on the Pi.
I try `tvservice -p` `tvservice -o` in various combinations seems to have little effect.
The Pi responds to keyboard (I can log on and see a new session over `ssh` on another computer), can restart, switch `tty`, but the display remains stubbornly blank.

I have tried `tvservice -c "PAL 4:3"` followed by `tvservice -p`
I have also tried switching virtual consoles, unsuccessfully.

Even restarting the Pi does not always work.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: I thought tvservice deals with the pi HDMI port - but your issue seems to be the monitor state ... have you looked into `cec-ctl`

Comment: you do not have a monitor with an HDMI port ... try a different HDMI-DVI converter

Comment: HDMI CEC is likely the way to go.